# How should we close Coverdell accounts with minimal penalties?

Tags: united-states, coverdell-esa

I have 2 kids that I had coverdell accounts for. We never used them for school expenses because we thought they could be used to pay off loans which I now know we can't. Both of my kids are now over 30 and I just found out these funds should have been disbursed before their 30th birthdays. how should we proceed to closing these accounts with the least penalties?

Comment: When did they turn 30? Is there a younger family member that can be designated as the beneficiary? Such as do your kids have kids? see https://www.irs.gov/publications/p970#en_US_2019_publink1000178449 for a list of family members.

Comment: I am surprised the bank or financial company didn't force them to liquidate the funds within 30 days of them turning 30.